# Make a cropping frame

Tags: html, frame, crop

Make a frame by changing the start of the cut.
I want to insert a html code but make an indentation so that it appears only part of the picture.
I use the code below but I want to change the start point of the cropping frame. When I use this code it starts the cut in point 0.0 and would like to start at a different point.

Code:

```
<div style="width:430px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;">

<iframe width="530" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid…

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but it seems that you only want to show a part on an image, right? Maybe the CSS-property "clip" can help you.